# Get enum from value

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have a question about `enum` in Swift.
I declared my enum like this:

```
enum FirstEnum : CustomStringConvertible {
    case VALUE1
    case VALUE2
    case VALUE3

    var description: String {
        switch self {
            case .VALUE1:
                return "First value"
            case .VALUE2:
                return "Second value"
            case .VALUE3:
                return "Third value"
        }
    }

    func getFromCode(value:String) -> FirstEnum? {
        switch value {
            case "v1":
                return FirstEnum.VALUE1
            case "v2":
                return FirstEnum.VALUE2
            case "v3" :
                return FirstEnum.VALUE3
        }
    }
```

I need to get enum from a string (like a dictionary) so I expect this line should work:

```
let foo = FirstEnum.getFromCode("v1")
```

But XCode (7) expects a `FirstEnum` parameter for method `getFromCode` instead a `String` as declared in method definition, saying:

> Cannot convert value of type "String" to expected argument type
>   "FirstEnum"

Why this?...what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `static` func so that you can call it without an instance of the enum:

```
static func getFromCode(value:String) -> FirstEnum? {
    switch value {
    case "v1":
        return FirstEnum.VALUE1
    case "v2":
        return FirstEnum.VALUE2
    case "v3" :
        return FirstEnum.VALUE3
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

You were getting the error because there is a hidden parameter when calling a method that is the instance of the enum.  Admittedly, the error message could be better.

Without `static`, you need an instance of the enum to call it.  Note that this works with the function as you had it defined:

```
let foo = FirstEnum.VALUE3.getFromCode("v1")
```

Also, your `switch` needs to be exhaustive, which is why I added the `default` case.

Comment: ops..I forgot `static` keyword! Thanks, now it works like a charm!

Comment: I think this is not the best solution. Look at Failable Initializers for Enumerations below

Answer (score 5):

Use [Failable Initializers for Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

> You can use a failable initializer to select an appropriate
>   enumeration member based on one or more parameters. The initializer
>   can then fail if the provided parameters do not match an appropriate
>   enumeration member.
>
> The example below defines an enumeration called TemperatureUnit, with
>   three possible states (Kelvin, Celsius, and Fahrenheit). A failable
>   initializer is used to find an appropriate enumeration member for a
>   Character value representing a temperature symbol:

```
enum TemperatureUnit {
    case Kelvin, Celsius, Fahrenheit
    init?(symbol: Character) {
        switch symbol {
        case "K":
            self = .Kelvin
        case "C":
            self = .Celsius
        case "F":
            self = .Fahrenheit
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift, you can derive your enum from `String`.

```
enum FirstEnum : String {
    case VALUE1 = "First value"
    case VALUE2 = "Second value"
    case VALUE3 = "Third value"

    static func getFromCode(value:String) -> FirstEnum? {
        switch value {
        case "v1":
            return FirstEnum.VALUE1
        case "v2":
            return FirstEnum.VALUE2
        case "v3" :
            return FirstEnum.VALUE3
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your `getFromCode` method should be static and needs a default clause.

But you don't need this method when you derive from String. To construct your enum value , you can use the `rawValue` like following:

```
let value = FirstEnum(rawValue: "First value")
```